# How to go to fragment from an activity if I came to the activity form the fragement?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I came to the activity class as for need from an fragment and now I want to go back to my earlier fragment.But The fragment was came from an drawer layout.I can't understand what to do....
here is my code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_answered, container, false);

    GridView answeredGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.answeredQuestiongridview);
    answeredImageAdapter = new AnsweredImageAdapter(getActivity());
    answeredImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    answeredGridView.invalidateViews();
    answeredGridView.setAdapter(answeredImageAdapter);
    answeredImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    answeredGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity()," "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            questionposition = position;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnswerDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Image_position",position);
            intent.putExtra("question_id",id);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();


        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Suppose now I am in this activity page. and want to go back to my fragment page..I wrote following code and facing the app is unfortunately stopped.

```
 private void answerFragment() {
          answeredFragment = new AnsweredFragment();
          fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
          //answeredFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById("myFragment");
          android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
          fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container,answeredFragment);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: how many activity you used in ur application

Comment: what happen when you press the hardware back button?

Comment: Almost 4 activity in my entire application but I used one fragment to go to a specific activity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the approach you are following is wrong. Fragments are tied to specific activities. From your code, it seems that in your **XYZActivity**, you have the **AnsweredFragment**. On click of an answer you are going to **AnswerDetailsActivity**. If you are doing it in the same way, then just remove `getActivity().finish();` call from here -

```
 answeredGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity()," "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        questionposition = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnswerDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Image_position",position);
        intent.putExtra("question_id",id);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();


    }
});
```

In that case, on your Back(Hardware/Software) press you will be able to load your earlier fragment. :)

Comment: Thank You I remove getActivity().finish();

Comment: Glad to help you. If you can, please mark my answer as a correct answer. So, that other people can get guided by my answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Brother I solved my problem without going to the fragment from activity but I also want to know that is that possible to go back to the fragment  from activity that activity comes from fragment?